# numpy: floor values of array to different array of values (similar to np.floor)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, floor

It is kind of hard to explain exactly what I mean, therefore I give an example of the function I would like:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
b = [0, 4, 5]
c = np.func(a, b)

print(c)
-->[[0, 0, 0],
    [4, 5, 5],
    [5, 5, 5]]
```

In words: every element of an array (a) should be lowered to the closest lower value of another array (b). The values could be floats.
I could do this in a loop, but I'm sure there is a numpy way of doing this.

Any tips much appreciated.

Comment: Please include how you do this in a loop.

Comment: If *b* is sorted and contains a valid floor value for every element in *a*: `np.array(b)[np.greater_equal.outer(a,b).sum(2) - 1]`, IIUC

Comment: Or `np.array(b)[np.digitize(a, b)-1]`.

Comment: Thanks you, this worked!
The loop I used was:

`c  = np.zeros_like(a)`

`prev = 0`

`for i in b:`

    `c[np.logical_and(a <= i, a > prev)] = prev`

    `prev = i`

Comment: btw. is there a propper way to show multiline code here?